# @font face only displaying in demo html

Tags: css, font-face

Ok so I downloaded a @font-face kit from fontsquirell, it works fine in the demo html file included in the download, but fails to render when I put it in any other file or sub folder.

I have checked the file structure and linked accordingly, i am still having this problem. Any suggestions on what I should do?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'BreeSerifRegular';
src: url('..assets/fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: local("☺")
     url('..assets/fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'),
     url('..assets/fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('..assets/fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('..assets/fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.svg#BreeSerifRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

The same format works for other fonts, dunno why its not working for this.

Comment: make sure the path is correct. It is correct is demo, but might not be the same path, when you shift it to your code

Comment: are you using a framework or CMS? because there will be path issues especially when using routes

Comment: Could you check the Error Console, Developer Console, or Javascript Console for errors? I know that this has nothing to do with Javascript, but resource load failures often appear here anyway.

Comment: i am just using basic html/css and i double checked the path..im sure its correct. I know this for sure because it works with other fonts when i replace it, just not with this one.

Comment: i checked the console, it says failure resource and then displays the path to the font. I dont know why its saying that, the path is definitely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the basic problem with paths

Copy the fonts you receive and into a folder at the root lets say a `font`.

Then point your css to read the file in a **relative** pattern like

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'BreeSerifRegular';
src: url('fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: local("☺")
     url('fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'),
     url('fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/BreeSerif-Regular-webfont.svg#BreeSerifRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

---

#### UPDATE

The way you are defining relative path is wrong

Change `..assets` to `../assets`

Comment: yes i did..i copied all the fonts from the downloaded file into a  subfolder named fonts which was placed in a another folder called assets which is in the root, hence the relative path used, but no progress. I am sure the path is correct.

Comment: @indrago, then `..assets` is an incorrect relative path. use `../assets`

Comment: yes that worked! Thank you so much..dont know how i missed that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @indrago, see I told you it was problem of path. I updated my answer with it.